# Load the same object into two b-form-select using the v-model - VueJS(bootstrap-vue)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I need to load inside several select, the value loaded inside my object "objectSelected", however it is not loading inside the bootstrap-vue form.

It does not display any error, it simply does not load.

```
//My selectors:
<b-col md="3" sm="12">
    <b-form-group label-for="object-myvalue" label-size="sm" class="mt-0 mb-0">
        <b-form-select 
            v-model="objectSelected"
            readonly
            disabled
            size="sm">
            <option :key="obj.code" v-for="obj in myArrayObjects" v-bind:value="obj">{{ obj.myvalue }}</option>
        </b-form-select>
    </b-form-group>
</b-col>
<b-col md="3" sm="12">
    <b-form-group label-for="object-description" label-size="sm" class="mt-0 mb-0">
        <b-form-select 
            v-model="objectSelected"
            readonly
            disabled
            size="sm">
            <option :key="obj.code" v-for="obj in myArrayObjects" v-bind:value="obj">{{ obj.description }}</option>
        </b-form-select>
    </b-form-group>
</b-col>

//My Data - return:
data: function() {
    return {
        objectSelected: {
            description: '',
            code: '',
            myvalue: '',
        },
        myArrayObjects: [],
    }
}

//Method that loads the value in the select:
loadValue() {
    this.objectSelected.code = 11
}
```

My method "loadValue" open the modal for use objectSelected, well after opening, simple not loading itens object in v-models.

Other v-model what utilize other objects, open perfect.

*I use bootstrap-vue version: "bootstrap-vue": "2.0.0-rc.13",*

Answer (score 0):

`<b-form-select>` has `options` prop, you can bind this with your options array, for example:

```
<template>
...
  <b-form-select
    v-model="selectedItem"
    :options="myOptions"
  />
...
</template>

<script>
...
  data:()=>({
    selectedItem: null,
    myOptions:[
      {value:"", text:""}, // this will set the selectedItem with string
      {value:{}, text:""}, // this with object
    ]
  })
...
</script>
```